# Battleships for iPhone Lieutenant Level 13

Tags: ios, battleships

Is there a bug in this level?  Seems like it can't be solved if the piece you are given is truly the center of the 3-spot ship.

Comment: This game is really a pain in the ass because you can't see your solution after you've gotten it. I solved level 13 and I just tried it again to see if I could help you but now I am now stuck on 13 too. I'll let you know if I crack it... and could use some help on 16 if you are able to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it... I'm not sure how this will read after posting but:

```
---o-o-2 Line 1
-o-o---2 Line 2
-o-----1 Line 3
-o----o2 Line 4
------o1 Line 5
-------0 Line 6
o-o----2 Line 7
1312012
```

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! I've fixed the formatting of your solution. As for your other question, please ask it as its own proper question using the ASK QUESTION button in the top right. Answers are meant to address the question given, not to follow-up with your own questions. If you have not yet done so, please also review our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Nice! That did the trick